# Usage of gem darwinning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So I am trying to use this gem called 'darwinning' in my rails application

First of all,I am not very sure where to include the custom class that I create.

I want to initialize the GENE_RANGES constant in the controller(or the @genes class instance variable) , and then run the algorithm to generate best member in the controller.

I tried declaring a 'initialize' method inside the custom class to set the values for GENE_RANGES, and then use it in the controller. But that isn't working.

How to go about implementing this?

Comment: much easier to answer if you show your code attempt, not just describe it.